# Checking if password contains symbols as well DOES NOT WORK

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript I tried to add a function like this for checking if the entered password contains any symbol (special) character such as `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?`.

So I did this:

```
        function checkpasswordlength(){
            var format1 = /^[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/;
            var e = document.getElementById("password").value;
            if(e != "") {
                if(e.length >= 12){
                    if(e.match(format1)){
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.display = "inline";
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").innerHTML = "strong";
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.setProperty('background-color', '#3cb878', 'important');
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.display = "inline";
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").innerHTML = "normal";
                        document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.setProperty('background-color', '#3cb878', 'important');
                    }
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").innerHTML = "weak";
                    document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.setProperty('background-color', 'red', 'important');
                }
            }else{
                document.getElementById("passwordstrengthstatus").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

As you can see, it will check if the password is not empty and it's length is more than `12` characters, then go ahead and check for `e.match(format1)`.

But the problem is, when I enter those characters as well, it will not return this condition as true and therefore the message **`strong`** does not appear and still shows **`normal`** message on screen.

So what's going wrong with this?

How can I solve this problem and properly check if the string contains the written symbols or not?

Comment: The problem is with ^ which checks is string starts with and $ for ends with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check for the presence of at least one symbol character, then remove the `^` and `$` anchors and just use:

```
var format1 = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?-]/;
```

Note that the hyphen has been moved to the end of the character class.  If you want to stick with your original pattern and match the entire password, then modify to this:

```
var format1 = /^.*[!@#$%^&*()_+\=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?-].*$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current regex matches only if the password contains nothing but special characters. try adding a-zA-Z0-9 inside too

`^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$`